# Singleton between different controller actions in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, design-patterns, singleton

Assume we have singleton class

```
class Registry {

    private static $_instance;

    private function __construct() {}
    private function __wakeup() {}
    private function __clone() {}

    private  $_map = array();

    public static function getInstance () {
        if (self::$_instance === null)
            self::$_instance = new self();
        return self::$_instance;
    }

    public function set ($key, $val) {
        self::getInstance()->_map[$key] = $val;
        return self::getInstance();
    }

    public function get($key)
    {
        if (array_key_exists($key, self::getInstance()->_map))
            return self::getInstance()->_map[$key];
        return null;
    }

}
```

And we have simple Symfony2 Controller with 2 actions

```
class IndexController {
        public function indexAction () {
          Registry::getInstance()->set('key',true);
          return new Response(200);
        }
        public function secondAction () {
          $val = Registry::getInstance()->get('key');
          return new Response(200);
        }
}
```

I call index action, then second action. But I can't find key, that was set in first action. I think, new instance of singleton creates in my second action. Why object is not saved in memory? What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you call `indexAction` and `secondAction` in different requests it won't work the way you want it because your `Registry` instance is not shared between requests.

`Singleton` itself does not store anything "in memory" (BTW `Singleton` is now considered as an [anti-pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)).

What, I think, you want to achieve can be done by using session storage. Check [doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/sessions.html) for more info how to implement this.